# Caching Issue With Spring Boot + Hazelcast +Kubernates

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, caching, hazelcast

I implemented a second-level cache with the use of HazelCast with Kubernates.
My configuration of the property file is below.

...

```
Spring:
jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          region:
              factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
          use_second_level_cache: true
```

...

Hazelcast Configuration

...

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private StaticConfig staticConfig;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config hazelCastConfig) {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setManagementCenterConfig(new ManagementCenterConfig());

        JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();

        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true).
            setProperty(HazelcastConstants.NAMESPACE, staticConfig.getHazelcastNamespace())
            .setProperty(HazelcastConstants.SERVICE_DNS, staticConfig.getHazelcastServiceDns());

        // disable multicast config for demo
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig()
            .setEnabled(false);

        EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig();
        evictionConfig.setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE);
        evictionConfig.setSize(500);

        MapConfig usersMapConfig = new MapConfig()
            .setName(ApplicationConstants.CACHE_NAME)
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(staticConfig.getCacheTimeToLive()))
            .setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig);

        config.addMapConfig(usersMapConfig);

        return config;
    }

}
```

...

Exception :
...

Sep 28, 2022 12:54:05 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
WARNING: [172.17.0.4]:5702 [dev] [4.1.5] Connection[id=148, /172.17.0.4:49607->/172.17.0.3:9191, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.3]:9191, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=148, /172.17.0.4:49607->/172.17.0.3:9191, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.3]:9191, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.recursing_bhabha.IO.thread-in-2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)

Sep 28, 2022 12:54:05 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
WARNING: [172.17.0.4]:5702 [dev] [4.1.5] Connection[id=147, /172.17.0.4:35573->/172.17.0.2:9193, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.2]:9193, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=147, /172.17.0.4:35573->/172.17.0.2:9193, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.2]:9193, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.recursing_bhabha.IO.thread-in-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)

Sep 28, 2022 12:54:05 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
WARNING: [172.17.0.4]:5702 [dev] [4.1.5] Connection[id=149, /172.17.0.4:33017->/172.17.0.2:9193, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.2]:9193, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=149, /172.17.0.4:33017->/172.17.0.2:9193, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.2]:9193, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.recursing_bhabha.IO.thread-in-0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)

Sep 28, 2022 12:54:05 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
WARNING: [172.17.0.4]:5702 [dev] [4.1.5] Connection[id=150, /172.17.0.4:59623->/172.17.0.3:9191, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.3]:9191, alive=false, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=150, /172.17.0.4:59623->/172.17.0.3:9191, qualifier=null, endpoint=[172.17.0.3]:9191, alive=true, connectionType=NONE, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.recursing_bhabha.IO.thread-in-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: HTT
at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.UnifiedProtocolDecoder.onRead(UnifiedProtocolDecoder.java:117)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:137)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294)
at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249)
at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)

Please any one Help me Out of it

Answer (score 0):

"*Unknown protocol: HTT*"

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/186)

Using `service-name` should be your solution.

Also, you should upgrade from 4.1.5, the latest is 5.1.3.